# Is there any dataset or free API available to convert or find Congressional Districts from zipcode

Tags: geolocation, dataset, geocoding, census

Is there any dataset or free  API available to convert or find Congressional Districts from zipcode

I need to find which Congressional Districts a pincode/zipcode belongs to or i need a dataset that help to map zipcode and Congressional Districts in US